# Flow to delete a file after x days

Tags: workflow, flow, power-automate

I'm trying to create a flow that will delete a file after 30 days from created date.
However, I am having trouble designing the condition, and I am not sure whether it is a simple expression, or I can use a dynamic content

My current flow:
Recurrence
Get file properties
Condition
If Yes- Delete File
If No - Do nothing

Many thanks,
Artur

Comment: In SharePoint, you have a feature titled Information Management Policy that does exactly what you are looking for out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dynamic content in condition. In this case your condition will be to subtract 30 days from Current_date (which is obtained using `Today()` formula), then you can go on to delete the files that were created after resultant_date that you calculate.